# Finding the most powerful test example - Did I do this correctly?

Tags: self-study, hypothesis-testing

I have 2 independent variables X and Y which are both normal with means $\theta$x and $\theta$y respectively and variance=1. I need to find the most powerful test of size $\alpha$=0.10 for the following hypotheses:

Ho: ($\theta$x, $\theta$y)=(0,0)
H1: ($\theta$x, $\theta$y)=(1,0)

My approach is as follows. First, I used the given that X and Y are independent and normal to get their joint pdf as just the product of their individual pdfs:

f[(x,y)|($\theta$x, $\theta$y)]=(1/2$\pi$)$^2$exp[-[(x-$\theta$x)$^2$+(y-$\theta$y)$^2$)/2]]

Then, using the Neyman-Pearson Lemma, I took the ratio of the joint pdf under the alternative hypothesis by the joint pdf under the null which ended with the expression:

exp(x-1/2)

Does this mean that using the NP lemma and letting exp(x-1/2)>k, the test that rejects Ho if x > lnk+1/2 is the most powerful test?

Also, in order to achieve size $\alpha$=0.10, I computed for k such that P(x>lnk+1/2)=0.10 which turns out to be 2.18486. Does this mean that the most powerful test of size $\alpha$=0.10 is the test where Ho is rejected when x>1.2815?

Finally, I noticed that the ratio using NP lemma simplified to just x (y was cancelled out). Is this because $\theta$y is the same in both the null and the alternative? If so, would I get the same answer if I just removed y from the start and worked with just one variable?

Thank you so much for your continued patience and generosity.

Comment: A little additional background, I'm studying for some tests that I have to take in a couple of months. I do have a background in this but am admittedly rusty.